# FTP populate jtree with files & directories from server

Tags: java, swing, apache, ftp, jtree

Am using Apache commons and am trying to show specified files and directories from a server,does anyone know how to do this,av used this code so far but its really not working. Can someone help out or show me where am going wrong.

```
 public String[] getDir(String rootDirectory) {
    String server = "192.168.1.11";
    int port = 21;
    String user = "javaapp";
    String pass = "nascalebio";
    String Directory = "/cms";
    String[] directories;

    FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();

    try {
        ftpClient.connect(server, port);
        ftpClient.login(user, pass);

        FTPFile[] files = ftpClient.mlistDir(Directory);
        directories = new String[files.length];
        for (int i =0; i < files.length; i++) {
            directories[i] = files[i].getName();
            System.out.println(i);
            System.out.println(directories[i]);
            System.out.println(files.length);
           }

        return directories;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return null;

}

public void buildtree(String currentdir, DefaultMutableTreeNode model) throws SocketException, IOException {
    String[] currentcrawl = getDir(currentdir);
    for (String node : currentcrawl) {
    DefaultMutableTreeNode currentnode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(node);
    buildtree(currentdir +"/" + node, currentnode);
    model.add(currentnode);

    }



    buildtree(".", root);
    tree.setModel(new DefaultTreeModel(root));
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider the several related examples examined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15149565/230513). Basically you're going to need to build a `TreeModel`, such as `FileTreeModel`, and use it in a view, such as `JTree` or `Outline`. Because of network latency, you'll need to fetch files in the background, perhaps using `SwingWorker`, and update your `TreeModel` in your implementation of the worker's `publish()` method.

Comment: I know how to do that on my local P.C but to fetch files from a remote server via Apache commons and place them in a jtree is what am looking for.......any help

Comment: The calls to the Apache library would go in the worker's `doInBackground()` method; I'd say `publish()` each `FTPFile` returned by the engine's `getNext()`.

Comment: Having a code that does that is what i need am new to java an d really struggling......am teaching myself all these and am stuck.....can i please get an example of the code

Comment: I don't know where you're stuck. The entire program will likely be several hundred lines; please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that focuses on the problem you're having.