# How to focus on a folder from java program

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to open a folder from java program by using the following java code

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("d:\\abc"));
```

I can successfully opened `d:\\abc`, now this abc folder is having two sub folders `images`, and `songs` now my reuirement is to focus this folder then open it by depending on user given input at run time.

May be tomorrow these sub file names will be changed, but depending on user input i want to focus on corresponding sub folders and open them.

I tried lot of ways in google and stackoverflow also. But I didn't get proper way.

Comment: Once `Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File(..));` is called, the Java app. loses all 'control' of what happens after is it opened.  Perhaps this app. needs [`JFileChooser`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html) instead.  It allows more control and feedback for the app.

Comment: BTW - what has this really got to do with Swing, or anything to do with speech?  Voice controlled file browsing desktop app.?

Comment: @AndrewThompson yes i am getting input from user as voice command

Comment: @AndrewThompson can please elaborate about JFileChooser :)

Comment: The link I included in my first comment elaborates quite nicely about `JFileChooser`.  Can you please read it? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **Robot** class, by using this **Robot** class you can press key on keyboard programatically.
If user input is

> images

then user **Robot** class to press corresponding key programatically.

Here you can get tutorial on **Robot** class
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html

Answer (score 2):

Use a [`JFileChooser`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html) to display the local file system and get the user's selection. Alternatively, add a suitable [list](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html) or [tree](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/treeselectionlistener.html) selection listener to one of the display components cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15150756/230513).