# How to create expandable panels using swing?

Tags: java, swing, expand

I would like to create a list of expandand/collapse panels, like on this image:

[image: expandand collapse panels]

I haven't found any swing component for this, so I began to create something like this.
I tried to put buttons one under the other, which fill the available width, but doesn't really works. I can only see the last added one.

```
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    panel.add(new JButton("Delphi Projects"), BorderLayout.NORTH);
    panel.add(new JPanel(), BorderLayout.NORTH); // hidden panel
    panel.add(new JButton("Delphi Projects | Delphi Files"), BorderLayout.NORTH);
    panel.add(new JPanel(), BorderLayout.NORTH); // hidden panel
    panel.add(new JButton("Other Files"), BorderLayout.NORTH);
    panel.add(new JPanel(), BorderLayout.NORTH); // hidden panel
    panel.add(new JButton("C++ Builder Projects | C++ Builder Files"), BorderLayout.NORTH);
    panel.add(new JPanel(), BorderLayout.NORTH); // hidden panel

    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(panel);
```

Comment: Some related examples are cite [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15149565/230513).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can take a look to `JXTaskPaneContainer` and `JXTaskPane` from [SwingX](https://swingx.java.net/) project which have these advantages:

- They are components just like a `JPanel` is so no extra effort is required to work with them.
- Unlike accordions you can have more than one panel expanded at any
  time.
- They have a cool and smooth effect on collapsing/expanding events.
- Unlike trees/tree tables you don't have to mess with either [TreeModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreeModel.html) nor [TreeTableModel](http://javadoc.geotoolkit.org/external/swingx/org/jdesktop/swingx/treetable/TreeTableModel.html) at all. Also trees and tree tables are components intended to show data in a hierarhical form, not to add components into it.

If you don't like task panes and want to implement something on your own then you have `JXCollapsiblePane` (also available in SwingX API).

Check [SwingLabs Demos](https://swinglabs-demos.java.net/) for a complete set of SwingX components demo.

#### Screenshot

[image]

Comment: It seems the originally referenced sites are no more available. But the project still is at https://github.com/githubcatw/swingx-core

Answer (score 3):

Look at JXTreeTable from the SwingX project:
[image: JXTreeTable in action]

You might also look at JXTree, which is similar, and might be better, depending your exact needs.

Get it from [here](https://java.net/projects/swingx).

Answer (score 2):

The component you're looking for is an accordion. Have a look at this question:
[Accordion for Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944256/accordion-for-swing)

As to your code - you can only see the last one because you're adding them all to a panel with a `BorderLayout`, with `BorderLayout.North` as the layout constraint. Each one removes the previously added panel. Try switching to another layout - e.g. `BoxLayout`.

Comment: Accordion is a different component intended to show a single panel at any time. I dont' think this is what OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

you have to put a grid panel in your layout panel. so in the "north" part in your layout panel, just add a grip panel of one column and the number of raw you want