# How to add an existing JPanel to a TitledPane

Tags: java, swing

I currently have a row of JPanels that I add to a JFrame. I need these panels to be able to expand and collapse as to minimize the clutter on the JFrame.

Right now, I just create the JPanels and add them to the JFrame one at the time.

```
public void addFolderSearch(FolderSearchComp fsc) {
    folderCompPanel.add(fsc, folderCompPanel.getComponentCount());
    remake();
}
```

I've tried adding these FolderSearchComps (the JPanels) to a TitledPane and then adding the TitledPane to the JFrame, but the titledpane.setContent() wont take the JPanel as a parameter.

Is there any way to add a JPanel to a TitledPane and then adding that TitledPane to the JFrame?

Comment: When you say `TitledPane`, do you mean `javafx.scene.control.TitledPane` ? If that is the case, you are trying to mix Swing and JavaFX code. Adding Swing components to a JavaFX application is possible (see [the tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/8/embed_swing/jfxpub-embed_swing.htm)), but perhaps not what you were looking for

Comment: yes that is what i mean, is there any swing component similar to the titledpane? or any other workaround to expand and collapse the jpanel

Comment: You are looking for an ["accordion"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944256/accordion-for-swing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there any swing component similar to the titledpane? or any other
>   workaround to expand and collapse the jpanel

There is a complete set of Swing components extension in [SwingX](https://swingx.java.net/) library which includes titled pane, task pane and collapsible pane, just to mention the ones that you are looking for.

Take a look to this related Q&A: [How to create expandable panels using swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25703228/1795530). You might also want to have a look to the demos: [SwingLabs demos](https://swinglabs-demos.java.net/)