# JFrame with panel count depending from parameter

Tags: java, swing, layout

I am creating simple application in java - Eclipse - WindowBuilder Editor. JFrame`s contentPane has JGoodies FormLayout in which I have to place 3 or 4 Panels - depending on mode.

It is proper way to make *if* construction that decides if content pane will be divided 1x3 or 1x4(facilitation because between all I use relatedgaps and so on..)?

I am not sure if this is good approach but I do not know how can I do this in other way than *if* construction. It has to be practical and flexible approach - to handle resizing the window, et cetera..

Comment: Java is not JavaScript.  Developing a Swing application is not the same as developing a browser application.  Use an appropriate Swing layout manager, like GridBagLayout, and it won't matter whether you have 3 JPanels or 4 JPanels.  Oh, using a window builder for Swing creates more problems than it solves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Common approaches for dynamic layout include these:

- Use `revalidate()`, and possibly `repaint()`, to layout a `Container` again after adding or removing components, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15104660/230513).
- Replace the layout and `validate()` the `Container`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5751044/230513).
- Use `CardLayout` to replace one panel with another, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5655843/230513) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).